# Unable to clone github repository

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh

I have generated ssh keys from my terminal and placed an entry in my SSH keys section in github.com.

After that, I am just trying to clone my repository, but I get the following error message :

```
git clone git@github.com:XYZXY/XXXXXXXXXX.git

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/XYZXY/.ssh/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/.git/
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried this one too :

```
ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Connection refused
```

My question is :

1) Is source side blocking the connection ?
2) Is Target not allowing the connection ?

Comment: Are you using Github behind a restrictive firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command for more information.

```
telnet ssh.github.com 22
```

You should see something like this.

```
~ $ telnet ssh.github.com 22
Trying 192.30.253.122...
Connected to ssh.github.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-libssh-0.7.0
```

If you do not, then something (possibly a firewall block?) is preventing you from accessing github.

Comment: I'd like to add that some systems prefer to install netcat instead of telnet. If `telnet` is not found, just type `nc -v` instead.

Comment: I get : telnet: connect to address 192.30.253.123: Connection refused

Comment: So it is probably a firewall block..Thank you